# Vier Rows Siete Colonnes

Tags: pattern, language

Ausfüllen the espacios vides

```
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
  +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
1 | D4 | O1 | E3 | T1 | A1 | A2 |    |
  +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
2 | F0 | O1 | T2 | D1 |    | A1 | D4 |
  +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
3 | D3 | U1 |    | T3 | C3 | O1 | S4 |
  +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
4 |    | E3 | N1 | D2 | R2 | I2 | D2 |
  +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

**Hints**

1. > Each row contains the same things.
2. > Start by ignoring the digits of the codes, they depend on the things identified by the characters and will be a new challenge once you have discovered the content.
3. > The order of the row's entries is determined by the row, and $2$ rows have the same order.

Comment: What exactly to do with the alphanumeric codes? Is there any pattern to solve for the answer?

Comment: @ABcDexter added 3 hints to get you going, I think it may be a tough puzzle without.

Comment: Por qué ist es auf Deutsch y en español?

Comment: @JoeZ. I think you mean to ask, "Warum use varios langues?".

Comment: Oh, "colonnes" is French! D: That makes sense.

Comment: I kept assuming those words were in Spanish as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** Jetzt the solución entière. Die four líneas représentent:

> The four rows correspond to the four languages in the title and in the question: German, English, Spanish and French, in that order.

Die four columnas représentent:

> The seven columns are the seven days of the week, but not in alphabetical order. (Thanks to ffao for pointing that out.) The letters are the first letter of the day in the respective language in the first columns, the second letter of the day in the second column and so on.
>
>  The days are:
>
>  `de:   Dienstag  dOnnerstag  frEitag   mitTwoch  montAg     samstAg   sonntaG`
>  `en:   Friday    mOnday      saTurday  sunDay    thurSday   tuesdAy   wednesDay`
>  `es:   Domingo   jUeves      luNes     marTes    miérColes  sábadO    vierneS`
>  `fr:   Dimanche  jEudi       luNdi     marDi     mercRedi   samedI    vendreDi`

Und the números sont:

> The numbers are counts of the letters that the sorted day of the week share with the number of the column in the corresponding language. Multiple occurrences of the same letter are counted as distinct letters:
>
>  `dIENStag  donnErstag  fREItag   mIttwoch  moNtag      SamStag   SoNntag`
>  `EINS      zwEi        dREI      vIer      fueNf       SechS     SiebeN`
>  `4         1           3         1         1           2         2`
>
>  `friday    mOnday      saTuRday  sUnday    thursday    tueSday   wEdNESday`
>  `one       twO         ThRee     foUr      five        Six       SEvEN`
>  `0         1           2         2         0           1         4`
>
>  `dOmiNgo   jueveS      lunES     mARTes    mIerCOles   Sabado    vIErnES`
>  `uNO       doS         trES      cuATRo    CIncO       Seis      SIEtE`
>  `2         1           2         3         3           1         4`
>
>  `dimaNche  jEUDi       lundI     mARdi     merCredI    SamedI    vEndredi`
>  `uN        DEUx        troIs     quAtRe    CInq        SIx       sEpt`
>  `1         3           1         2         2           2         1`
>
>  In comparison to the question, I've got different counts for *domingo* and *vendredi*. The number one causes problems for all languages except English, because it conflates with the indirect singular article. I've tried to use the variant that is used when counting.

Schliesslich, the table complète:

> `|       1    2    3    4    5    6    7`
>  `|     +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+`
>  `|   1 | D4 | O1 | E3 | T1 | A1 | A2 | G2 |`
>  `|     +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+`
>  `|   2 | F0 | O1 | T2 | D1 | S0 | A1 | D4 |`
>  `|     +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+`
>  `|   3 | D3 | U1 | N2 | T3 | C3 | O1 | S4 |`
>  `|     +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+`
>  `|   4 | D1 | E3 | N1 | D2 | R2 | I2 | D2 |`
>  `|     +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+`

Comment: The ordering is not arbitrary; they're all in alphabetical order (except for the last two in German, which I think you should swap)

Comment: @ffao: Very good, didn't see that. The insight might provide a new angle for the numbers. It also makes my comment about Sonnabend/Samstag moot.

Comment: Looking good so far

Comment: This is so close to correct that I am accepting - the counts are simply the number remaining in the first after removing any not in the second - this should "correct" the two you have out of line (and the top-right unknown).